# How to get Jest to find modules imported in components?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

When I try to run npm jest, the test suite fails to run and gives this error message:

```
Cannot find module 'app/utils' from 'MoreModal.js'

          1 | import React from 'react';
          2 | import { Link } from 'react-router';
        > 3 | import { fn, api } from 'app/utils';
```

My jest config is

```
"jest": {
        "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/js/__tests__/setup/setupEnzyme.js",
        "testPathIgnorePatterns": ["<rootDir>/js/__tests__/setup/"],
    },
```

I've tried fiddling with moduleDirectories, but that does nothing.

My enzyme setup is

```
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

The test:

```
describe('<MoreModal />', () => {
    describe('render()', () => {
        test('renders the component', () => {
            const wrapper = shallow(<MoreModal />);
            const component = wrapper.dive();

            expect(toJson(component)).toMatchSnapShot();
        })
    })
})
```

How do I get jest to correctly find the modules in the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bundler probably has something set up for resolution to make `app/utils` work like that.

If you're using Webpack, https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-webpack-resolver will help you wire up Jest to use the same resolution rules.

Comment: Thank you very much; that resolved the error. I'm now getting a type error regarding createStore -- TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please ask that as a new question, with the full error and traceback and relevant code included :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
"jest":{
    "modulePaths": [
        "<rootDir>/app"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
        "app"
    ]
}
```

According to [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#modulepaths-array-string):

> An alternative API to setting the NODE_PATH env variable, modulePaths
>   is an array of absolute paths to additional locations to search when
>   resolving modules. Use the  string token to include the path
>   to your project's root directory. Example: ["/app/"].

It is also possible that your bundler resolves your modules relative to a different directory as very well mentioned by @AKX. Is "app/utils" in the root folder of your project or inside a different one? If that's the case your jest configuration should match your bundler's.